# Deserializing .NET stream with multiple objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, stream

I have a MemoryStream which I write into as I receive data off the network. Since the data can be broken up, there is the potential for the stream to have a partial message or multiple messages stored in the stream. When deserializing, I place the pointer back at the beginning of the stream and try to deserialize a class of mine. I have the deserialize wrapped in a try catch block, but I get to the deserialize line, the application just quits out (no exception, not more lines run in the function, etc).

I have multiple questions:

1. What is the best way to receive a stream of XML data from the network that may or may not be complete, and if so may or may not have more than one message?
2. Does the deserializer need to know about the encoding to decode the XML within the MemoryStream?
3. Does deserialization place the stream pointer after the deserialized object?
4. Can you deserialize multiple objects within a single stream?

Comment: Please post the lines of code you use to serialize and deserialize the stream.  Typically, the network layer would be responsible for ensuring complete messages are received, not the deserialization code.  That aspect of your question confuses me.

Comment: You really need to figure out why the call to deserialize exits without an exception. In addition, if the deserializer gets an exception, it's pretty unlikely that it will be able to re-sync and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can leverage the XmlReader class which "provides forward-only, read-only access to a stream of XML data". That may help you translate xml data that may not be complete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.xml.xmlreader

2) If you are referring to the mixing ASCII, UTF-8, etc. then yes, otherwise I am not sure what the question is.

3) That depends on the deserializer you are using.

4) Yes, with the XMlReader class you can cleverly extract attributes and xml fragments for later consumption (although the solution is not elegant and rather ugly)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the stream is forward only though, when I attempt to deserialize and the pointer gets moved what happens to the data stored in the stream? Do I have to create a new stream?

Comment: And as for question 2, how do I tell the deserializer what encoding to expect the data in?

Comment: The data is always in your memorystream object (or where ever you allocated memory), and will reside there until you release it. If it's in a MemoryStream object, you would create a StreamReader object passing it the MemoryStream that contains your packet of data. You can specify encoding using that class.  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456(v=vs.110).aspx) You can "rewind" your stream by recreating the class or using the MemoryStream.Seek() command.